# I'm getting this error while updating the db

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

```cs
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductId{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int Stock{ get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    public bool IsHome { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate{ get; set; }
    public List<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Subcategory")]
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SubCategoryId")]
    public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Category")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategory
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }

}
```

And here are the `DBSet`s in the `DbContext`:

```cs
public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
public DbSet<ProductFavorite> ProductFavorites{ get; set; }
public DbSet<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
public DbSet<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
```

I give migrations the update-database command, I get the following error:

Error Number:1767,State:0,Class:16
"Foreign key 'FK_Products_Categories_CategoryId' references invalid table 'Categories'.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors."

Thanks in advance for your interest.

Comment: Is `Category` listed in your `DbSet` in the `DbContext` file?

Comment: Yes,DbContext:                                                                                                          public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
  public DbSet<ProductFavorite> ProductFavorites{ get; set; }
   public DbSet<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
   public DbSet<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
   public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

Comment: Can you post the DbContext in it's entirety in your question?

Comment: Db context : https://ibb.co/1K3tz7c

Comment: Confirm whether tables are named plurally or singularly. I.E. Category vs Categories. The error says it should be named Categories.

Comment: Which table should i change the name of the category ?

Comment: Can you show us the rest 5 classes? Since there is no problem when I do migration and update command with the 3 classes you provided.

Comment: Thanks for your support.I solved the error. :)